# Convert String to type of Page?

Tags: c#, windows-8, navigation, windows-store-apps

I want to Convert a string **DashBoard** to a type of page named as **DashBoard** because I wanted to use it in navigation purpose. Normally I navigate to some page like this

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DashBoard));
```

but I want to DashBoard page to be replaced by variable like this

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Somestring));
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you mean, but probably reflection is what you're after.

Comment: actually i want to convert string to page type..such that i can use the string variable directly in navigation method..because my string contain the name of the page on which i have to navigate

Comment: Yes, then Reflection is exactly what you need. If you want implicit conversion, you'd need to extend DashBoard and implement it yourself, but in the end it'd still make use of reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `Type.GetType(string)` [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

```
this.Frame.Navigate(Type.GetType(My.NameSpace.App.DashBoard,MyAssembly));
```

Read the remarks section on how to format the string.

Or you can use reflection:

```
using System.Linq;
public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static Type GetTypeByString(string type, Assembly lookIn)
    {
        var types = lookIn.DefinedTypes.Where(t => t.Name == type && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page)));
        if (types.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type you were looking for was not found", "type");
        }
        else if (types.Count() > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type you were looking for was found multiple times.", "type");
        }
        return types.First().AsType();
    }
}
```

This can be used as following:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(TypeHelper.GetTypeByString("TestPage", this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
}
```

In this example. The function will search in the current assembly for a page with the name TestPage and then navigate to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the fully qualified name of `DashBoard` - i.e. which assembly and namespace it's in - you can use reflection to determine what to pass to `Navigate`.

Look at [the docs for System.Reflection.Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly.aspx), in particular `GetTypes` and `GetExportedTypes`, depending on what you need.