# navigationservice.navigate not available on the vs2013 project

Tags: vb.net, xaml, .net-4.5

I have two page application and the main page is default is "MainPage.xaml" and the second one is "AddPerson.xaml" when user click a button on main page I want the app to take user to "AddPerson" page.

And I wrote following for the Click event of the button

```
Me.Frame.Navigate(System.Type.GetType("AddPerson.xaml"))
```

and I am getting the following error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MedicineSchedule.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I tried other method of navigationservice.navigate which I cannot find the class in VS2013 express at all. The only method available is Me.Frame.Navigate in my project, please let me know  how I can get this simple thing to work.

If it was .net 2.0 I would simple called new form with form.lod or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AddPerson));
```

If you want/have to use a string take a look at the reply here:

[convert string to type of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056433/convert-string-to-type-of-page)